# Slack API - Detecting user in a call?

Tags: slack-api

Is there an endpoint in Slack API to detect a user (AKA me) is in a call? `getPresence` just returns 'active' and 'away' which is not helpful - I can be active *but* not in a call.  I tried getting user status, that is of no help either

Answer (score 0):

There's no API that will return that information at this time. The `calls.info` method would return a list of users in a specific call but you'd need to know the call id for that. Something as simple as knowing if any given user is on a call would be a great feature request for the `users.getPresence` method. Happy to pass that along!